# Minimizing vector

Tags: functional-analysis

I have a doubt about that existence proof for this theorem

Let $X$ be an inner product space and $M$ non-empty a convex subset which is a complete (in the metric induced by the inner product). Then for every given $x\in X$ there exists a unique $y\in M$ such that

$$\delta = \inf_{\hat{y}\in M}||x-\hat{y}|| = ||x-y||.$$

Proof (a) Existence. By definition of an infimum there is a sequence $(y_n)$ in $M$ such that

$$\delta_n \longrightarrow \delta \,\,\,\,\,\text{ where }\,\,\,\,\,\delta_n=||x-y_n||\,\,\,\,(^*).$$

We show that $(y_n)$ is a Cauchy. Writing $y_n-x=v_n$, we have $||v_n||=\delta_n$ and 
$$||v_n+v_m||=||y_n+y_m-2x||=2||1/2(y_n+y_m)-x||\geq 2\delta$$
because $M$ is convex, so that $1/2(y_n+y_m)\in M$. Furthermore, we have $y_n-y_m=v_n-v_m$. Hence by the parallelogram equality,

$$||y_n-y_m||^2=||v_n-v_m||^2=-||v_n+v_m||^2+2(||v_n||^2+||v_m||^2)\leq -(2\delta)^2+2(\delta_n^2+\delta_m^2)(^{**})$$
and $(^*)$ implies that $(y_n)$ is Cauchy.

My question is Why $(^*)$ and $(^{**})$ implies that $(y_n)$ is Cauchy?. By definition of Cauchy sequence: $(y_n)$ is Cauchy if for every positive real number $\epsilon>0$, there is a positive integer $N$ such that for all natural numbers $m, n > N$, $||y_m-y_n||<\epsilon$. In the proof What's is a $N$? Who is $\epsilon$?

Comment: Dear @DavidMitra Can you help me with this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\delta_n=\delta$, then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\delta_n^2=\delta^2$. Fix $\varepsilon>0$, then from definition of limit there exist $N$ such that $n>N$ implies $\delta_n^2-\delta^2<\varepsilon^2/4$. Therefore, for all $m,n>N$ we have
$$
\Vert y_n-y_m\Vert^2=2(\delta_n^2-\delta^2)+2(\delta_m^2-\delta^2)<2\varepsilon/4+2\varepsilon/4=\varepsilon^2
$$
Thus for any $\varepsilon>0$ we found $N$ such that $m,n>N$ implies $\Vert y_n-y_m\Vert<\varepsilon$. Thus $\{y_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a Cauchy sequence.