# Prove $\exists x$ such that $\|Ax-b\|$ is minimal and this is unique if $A$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

Suppose $A\in \mathbb R^{m\times n}$. I'm supposed to prove $\exists x$ such that $\|Ax-b\|$ in minimal and this $x$ is unique if $A$ is invertible, in which case I also need to exhibit a formula.

I was thinking that since everything is finite dimensional, the image of $A$ (as an operator) is closed, so we can orthogonaly project $b$ onto it and obtain the solution. However, this seems like the only solution without assuming the invertibility of $A$... For a formula, I think the usual projection formula works, and it also doesn't involve the invertibility of $A$..

What am I missing?

Comment: That's the minimizing vector theorem. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415893/minimizing-vector

Comment: @MarioCarneiro that doesn't answer my question though, it just shows that we may work with closed convex subsets instead of closed subspaces. I'm asking about the relevance of $A$ and its invertibility here..

Comment: If $A$ is not invertible, it may sometimes be the case that $x$ is unique. But it is not always true: if $A=0$ then all $x$ have the same value of $||Ax-b||$.

Comment: What's your formula for finding the orthogonal projection? I bet you have to divide by $A$ somewhere...

Comment: Find a basis for the image of $A$ and sum the projections of $b$ along its elements

Comment: @MarioCarneiro I understand the bit about uniqueness now - though the projection to the image of $A$ is unique, the points in it can have big fibers.

Comment: Actually, I was a bit off above: if $A$ is not invertible, then $x$ is never unique. Because by definition of non-injectivity, $Ax=Ay$ for some $x\ne y$, and then $\|Ax-b\|=\|Ay-b\|$.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro right, that's exactly saying there *has* to be a big fiber

Comment: How can $A$ be invertible if it's not square? Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ be the image of $A$, and let $W\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be an orthogonal complement thereof. Then we can write uniquely $b=b_v+b_w$, with $b_v\in V$ and $b_w\in W$. Then anything from $\mathbb{R}^m$ mapping to $b_v$ will do the trick.

And for the uniqueness when $A$ is invertible (or better, when $\ker{A}=0$) follows immediately.